# Embedding photosphere in squarespace

Tags: html, css, iframe, squarespace

I'm trying to embed photospheres into Squarespace.

Google Maps works fine, but doesn't suit my needs and looks as follows:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1471028758208!6m8!1m7!1sF%3A-hjcchX5MD5g%2FV03OAcggYUI%2FAAAAAAAAKeM%2FXwIrucnK4IQkwWbhxu9BrvOATMYZaMmKgCLIB!2m2!1d37.870246!2d-119.360704!3f125.91384035181916!4f6.045852307800146!5f0.7820865974627469" width="100%" height="800" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Instead, I want to embed via sphereshere.net Their embed looks as follows but DOESN'T work.

```
<iframe src="http://sphereshare.net/#!/e/c467ba7af9753ee287cd44550493e966" height="320" width="620" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

What do we think is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, in cases like this, the problem is the use of the `http` protocol in an iframe while you're still logged into Squarespace via `https`. You should try to view the page while **not** logged in, being sure you're viewing the page via http and not https. If you provide a link to the page, I'm happy to take a look as well.

The reason for this has to do with browser security. Loading a resource over http while viewing the parent website over https is a potential security risk, so browsers do not allow it. Google maps supports loading over https (and you can see the link you're using for Google Maps uses https). Whereas sphereshare.net does not support https, so you're using http. When logged into Squarepace, you're loading the website over https but the sphereshare iframe over http, so browsers do not allow it.

In the future, hopefully you'll be able to use https with sphereshare, then it would work in either case. Until then, you'll have to log out and set your protocol to http in order to view iframes loaded over http.

Comment: Thanks! Was exactly what the issue was. Weird that one works through the normal preview and one doesn't but such is life!